# Equivalent operation to addsuffix/addprefix from Make in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given a space-separated list of words, how can I prefix (or suffix) all of them without executing any external command?

Make has such construct:

```
$(addprefix foo,bar baz)
⇒ foobar foobaz
```

Answer (score 3):

With bash 5.2 (currently in beta) or newer you can do:

```
bash-5.2$ shopt -s extglob patsub_replacement
bash-5.2$ string='foo bar baz'
bash-5.2$ printf '%s\n' "${string//+([^ ])/&suffix}"
foosuffix barsuffix bazsuffix
```

The equivalent of ksh93's:

```
printf '%s\n' "${string//+([^ ])/\0suffix}"
```

Or of `zsh`'s:

```
set -o extendedglob
printf '%s\n' "${string//(#m)([^ ])##/${MATCH}suffix}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) on the elements of an array. Convert your space-separated list to an array:

```
a=(bar baz bat)
```

then expand it, “replacing” the beginning of each item with your prefix:

```
printf "%s " "${a[@]/#/foo}"
```

You can suffix in the same way by using `%`:

```
printf "%s " "${a[@]/%/foo}"
```

You can also use shell parameter expansion on space-separated words, if those words are separated by single spaces, in two steps:

```
w="bar baz bat"
r="${w/#/foo}"
r="${r// / foo}"
```

(*i.e.* replacing the start of the string with the prefix, and replacing any space with a space followed by the prefix).

If the `extglob` `shopt` is enabled, this can also deal with repeated spaces:

```
w="bar baz bat"
r="${w/#/foo}"
r="${r//+( )/ foo}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for space-separated strings, but it is possible with arrays. And you can convert a space-separated string to an array.

Start with the variable with space-separated words:

```
words="foo bar baz"
```

Convert it into an array:

```
array=($words)
```

And add suffix:

```
echo -- "${array[@]/%/suffix}"
⇒ foosuffix barsuffix bazsuffix
```

Or add a prefix:

```
echo -- "${array[@]/#/prefix}"
⇒ prefixfoo prefixbar prefixbaz
```

Repeat to add both prefix and suffix.

Comment: That `array=($words)` splits on whatever characters `$IFS` currently contains, not necessarily only spaces and also performs globbing. bash's `echo` builtin doesn't support `--` (only fish' does AFAIK) and can't generally be used to output arbitrary data.